# Profiling Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We have a heavy project running on firebase with cloud functions in Blaze mode. How can we profile and gets detailed information about the following?

- What cloud functions are called?
- Whats the average response time?
- How much data is being passed in each function request?
- Are there any trigger failures related to firestore?
- How much memory is being used by each function instance?
- What functions are eligible for shifting to Cloud Run where we can avoid cold start?

Any suggestions on how others are getting this information/analytics will be of great help!

Comment: maybe this would help https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/five-metrics-you-should-follow-when-working-with-cloud-functions/

Comment: Amazing! Let me look into it quickly.

Comment: Hi @Ayyappa, did you manage to set up the profiling?

Comment: Currently using require-benchmark, require-so-slow modules with trace console. I can find out the loading times but not complete processing profiling though.